# Multiple rendering back ends architecture

Tags: c#, opengl, rendering, opentk

so I've been thinking about designing a rendering engine with multiple back ends in C#.

Well, let me rephrase; I wish to design an engine that can be easily extended upon to support multiple back ends. My primary goals is to use OpenGL, but maybe later I might to add support for DirectX or a software renderer.

So i was thinking about how I might achieve this and think I've come up with a pretty decent design, here it is (in code, just cause it's best to see the design visually)

Firstly, the interfaces

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an interface for low level rendering methods.
/// </summary>
public interface IRenderContext
{
    void Clear(bool colorBuffer, bool depthBuffer, bool stencilBuffer);

    // One a side note, should all the methods below be in some kind of resource manager???

    // Now for each type of resouce that can be used by the render context, lets
    // create and return an interface, rather than an object so that users don't have
    // to see an ugly class like "OpenGLMesh" or "DirectXRenderTarget".

    IMesh CreateMesh(Vertex[] vertices, int[] indices);

    ITexture CreateTexture(int width, int height, char[] pixelData);

    IShader CreateShader(ShaderType shaderType, string shaderSource);

    IRenderTarget CreateFrameBuffer(int width, int height);
}

/// <summary>
/// Defines an interface for high level rendering functions.
/// </summary>
public interface IRenderDevice
{
    // Lets contain the render context to make our lives easier
    IRenderContext RenderContext { get; }

    void DrawMesh(Transform transform, IMesh mesh, ITexture texture);

    // and other methods that are on more of a higher level would go here
}
```

and finally the way it would be used is like this:

```
IRenderContext renderContext = new OpenGLRenderContext();
IRenderDevice renderDevice = new OpenGLRenderDevice(renderContext);

ITexture texture = renderContext.CreateTexture(640, 480, pixelData);
IMesh mesh = renderContext.CreateMesh(vertices, indices);
renderDevice.DrawMesh(transform, mesh);
```

Is this a bad design? Am I missing something? What can I do to improve the architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Largely echoing Josh, I think this is very difficult to do. After all, if we could generalize abstractions that allow us to write code against any kind of backend while still being able to express what we want to do at the low-level of what primitives to render and so forth, we'd all be writing code against such an abstraction and there'd be little point to writing code specifically for OpenGL or DirectX or anything else.

Instead a much easier thing to do typically is abstract your game state instead of the renderer. Then you can have multiple concrete rendering backends that render such state, and such implementations would be free to do whatever since they don't have to conform to any abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks incomplete and/or overly-simplified. It consequently probably won't scale up very well to more complex rendering scenarios. It probably won't work well for anything but the first rendering backend you build for it, either.

Texture and buffer resources are pretty similar, conceptually, across most rendering APIs: they're the easy part. State management beyond those resources are usually where things get complicated and fiddly to port between APIs, and your abstraction doesn't account for that *at all*. Even with the resources you're not accounting for all the varied usage modes and behavioral control flags a robust API is going to want - can this be read on the CPU, can it be bound as a render target, where does it exist in GPU memory, et cetera.

It's a reasonable *start*, and continuing along this path will be very educational for you. I suggest you simply proceed, keeping aware that you'll have to refactor the design as you want to write more complex rendering code, and as you port it. I'd also suggest that if you *really* want to make this kind wrapper you immediately being implementing it in more than one backend (say, OpenGL and D3D). Pick one you like better, build parts of your API in that backend first, and then try making it work with the other backend. You should discover pretty quickly where there are interesting differences that challenge your assumptions and force you to refactor your design, and that will ultimately lead to a much better API.

It will also make it much less daunting (and more likely that you'll actually finish) to have it work on two different rendering backends if you can develop them mostly in lockstep.

You may want to take a look at other API abstractions; [sokol](https://github.com/floooh/sokol) is in C, but it's a pretty good, minimal example you can look at. [BGFX](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx) is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

After allot of searching, I've found something scales nicely and is quite simple to expand.

Here's a link, if you follow it you'll also a few articles on the topic and how it was designed, it's pretty much a tutorial.

https://github.com/amesgames/RenderDevice/tree/develop